# Hiding Parent Div with jQuery

Tags: html, jquery

I have a div I am trying to hide with a value of 9.  This is what I have so far.  But it's not working...

**My Hide Function**:

```
<script>
$('.hhpt-housebox').each(function() {
          if($(this).val() < 9){
              $(this).parent().hide();
          }
});
</script>
```

HTML

```
<div class="hhpt-colorbox hhpt-housebox">
   <div class="hhpt-clickbox" mychoice="0" myvalue="9"><span class="hhpt-housethumb"></span>
<span class="hhpt-housetitle">Chicken Coop<span></span></div>
   <a class="hhpt-greencirclebutton hhpt-infocorner" href="#hhpt-pop-9" rel="hhpt-modal:open">
<i class="hhpt-icon-circle-info"></i></a>
</div>
```

FIDDLE:
https://jsfiddle.net/j5t3pa82/

However, it is displaying this still:

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yRlgG.png): [image]

Comment: .hhpt-housebox does not have a value property and val() has to w the value of an inputs...i do not see any input in the markup

Comment: What would be the proper way to hide the parent div and everything inside of it then?

Comment: Your fiddle and your question don't match up.  Your fiddle, everything is hidden, as does the code you've provided, so where's the "chicken coop" in your fiddle/question?   Add a console.log to see what's happening - `.val()` on a div is always `""` which is always `<9`: https://jsfiddle.net/5tLo2kmx/

Comment: Minimal changes to your existing code would be: `if (($(this).attr("myvalue")*1) < 9) {` - but you *should* be using `data-myvalue` for custom attributes

Answer (score 0):

Divs don't have a value, that's only available for user input controls.

Use a `data-XXX` attribute to add application-specific data to elements. Then you can filter on that.

Also, it looks like the elements whose value you want to check are the `.hhpt-clickbox` child elements.

```js
$('.hhpt-housebox').filter(function() {
  return $(this).find(".hhtp-clickbox").data("value") < 9;
}).hide();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="hhpt-colorbox hhpt-housebox">
  <div class="hhpt-clickbox" mychoice="0" data-value="9"><span class="hhpt-housethumb"></span>
    <span class="hhpt-housetitle">Chicken Coop<span></span></div>
  <a class="hhpt-greencirclebutton hhpt-infocorner" href="#hhpt-pop-9" rel="hhpt-modal:open">
    <i class="hhpt-icon-circle-info"></i></a>
</div>
```

Comment: Or switch it around: (not worth a separate answer):  `$(".hhtp-clickbox").filter((i,e)=>$(e).data("value") < 9).closest(".hhpt-housebox").hide();`

Answer (score 0):

`div` is a block element and doesn't have value attributes. Here, you can fetch the value through the attributes and with jquery [attr](https://api.jquery.com/attr/).

As you're comparing with the integer value `9`, the fetched value is casted to integer with `+`

```
$(function() {
  $('.hhpt-clickbox').each(function() {
        
  var val = +($(this).attr("myvalue")); //casting to integer
  
    if (val < 9) {
      $(this).parent().hide();
    }
  });
});
```